# Finding value of unchecked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a database with NES game titles and I am displaying a list of the games with a checkbox near it.  It is an inventory/tracking system so if you own the game, you check the box.  The checkboxes have an id of 'nes#' where the '#' is a number (e.g., nes1, nes2, nes3..).

I have been able to so far, get a list of all checkboxes that are checked, and then save the id's (value of the checkbox) to a Javascript array.

So, with that in mind, I wanted to do the opposite now and get a list of all checkboxes that are NOT checked and then save that list to an array.  Thought it would be simple.

Overall goal is to be able to remove a record from the database if the user NO LONGER owns that game.  So in this case, the user would uncheck the box, and hit save. Upon hitting save, the code would then look at the list of unchecked boxes/the id and then if it exists in the database, remove it as the user does not own the game anymore.

If there is a better way to do this, then I am open to suggestions as well.

Here is code I have so far:

```
          //CHECK FOR REMOVED ITEMS
          var x = 1;
          var nesGameIDsToRemove = new Array();

          //nesGameIDsToRemove = [].filter.call( $('input[id^=nes]'), e => ! e.checked ).map( e => e.value ); 

          while (x <= <?php echo $nesCount; ?>){
            //check each NES checkbox
            if (!$('#nes' + x).is(":checked")){
                console.log($('#nes' + x).val());
                nesGameIDsToRemove.push($('#nes' + x).val());
            }
            x++;
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < nesGameIDsToRemove.length; ++i) {
            console.log(i + ': ' + nesGameIDs[i]);
            $.post('updateInventory.php', {'gameID': nesGameIDsToRemove[i], 'userID': <?php echo $profileID; ?>, 'mode': 2, 'console': "NES"}, function (response) {
                $('#inventoryResults').html(response);
            });
          }

     //Break in code

                <input type='checkbox' id='nes1' name='nes1' value='1'>10 Yard Fight(1)<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='nes2' name='nes2' value='2'>1942(2)<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='nes3' name='nes3' value='3'> ..... continued
```

Comment: Please remove the PHP components, once the resulting HTML is passed to the client they're utterly irrelevant; what matters is the final JavaScript and the HTML that's sent to the browser.

Comment: Ok, left in what I feel is relevant though.

Comment: The line I gave in chat works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/2x0wugv6/  This means the error is perhaps in somewhere else.  Try to learn debug, both php and js, to see what is going on.  If you can narrow down the problem, the question will be more specific.

Comment: @Sheepy I am able to see the values (which are the IDs in console.log printout)  but the issue is when I try to add the values to the array.  Does this help narrow it down at all?  If my code to display the value is correct, then not sure why I cant put it in the array?

Comment: @Retro No. Because your code looks ok and works ok too. The problem is not in that few lines: https://jsfiddle.net/2x0wugv6/2/

Comment: @Retro what is the issue you are facing when you try to add value to the array? The code inside the second for loop does not execute at all?

Comment: One thing which noticed in the code is "console.log(i + ': ' + nesGameIDs[i])" line has differnet array name than the one which is populated in previous loop. I am not sure if that's intentional.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes I am seeing now that this is breaking the code, and likely causing issues.  Didnt notice that.. Thanks, will update soon.

Answer (score 0):

As Chetan noticed, the issue was that I was referencing the wrong array in the code and so it was breaking there.  "One thing which noticed in the code is "console.log(i + ': ' + nesGameIDs[i])" line has differnet array name than the one which is populated in previous loop. I am not sure if that's intentional. – Chetan Ranpariya 15 mins ago"

Then it was just a matter of changing some php code logic which was backwards.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Your lookup is unnecessarily complicated.  Just do:

```
var nesGameIDsToRemove = $('input:not(:checked)').get().map(el=>el.id);
```